# Ruby installation failed

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl

I am trying to install newer versions of ruby > 2.4 using rvm and rbenv on macos Catalina. I have the newest version of openssl in homebrew. The process fails while making ruby.
Following is last few lines before rbenv failed

```
linking miniruby
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_assert", referenced from:
      _enum_sum in enum.o
      _sum_iter in enum.o
      _rb_int_digits_bigbase in numeric.o
      _rb_fix_digits in numeric.o
     (maybe you meant: _rb_assert_failure)
rb_mjit_header.h updated
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
```

Output from rvm is

```
ruby-2.7.1 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/********/.rvm/log/1593732271_ruby-2.7.1/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Log

```
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
./revision.h unchanged
compiling version.c
building rb_mjit_header.h
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_assert", referenced from:
      _enum_sum in enum.o
      _sum_iter in enum.o
      _rb_int_digits_bigbase in numeric.o
      _rb_fix_digits in numeric.o
      _range_last in range.o
     (maybe you meant: _rb_assert_failure)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use both rvm and rbenv. I don't know exactly what would happen, but they'll likely conflict with one another, as they'll both try to control where Ruby versions are installed and how the correct version is chosen.

I would completely uninstall both, undo anything in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/`.bash_profile` etc that you did for rbenv and rvm.

Then, start over with just one or the other.

Comment: Initially, I had the only rvm and I added rbenv only after trying a number of solutions. I followed your suggestion but the problem is the same.

Comment: Can you paste the full output? Clear everything out, then paste everything outputted after you type `rbenv install 2.7.1` or `rvm install 2.7.1`. Those compilation errors generally have to do with C compilation dependencies on OSX like Command Line Tools, gcc, etc.